# Shade area between 2 curves

Tags: r, plot

I can't seem to wrap my mind arround how polygon() works. I've searched a lot but I cant seem to understand how polygon wants the x,y points and what do they represent.

Could someone please help me and explain how to shade for example the area between the red and blue line

```
curve(x/2, from=0 , to =1, col="darkblue")
curve(x/4, from=0 , to =1, add=T, col="darkred")
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because, in this case, there isn't really any curve to the line you could use something very simple (that highlights how polygon works).

```
x <- c(0,1,1,0)
y <- c(x[1:2]/2, x[3:4]/4)
polygon(x,y, col = 'green', border = NA)
```

Now, if you had a curve you'd need more vertices.

```
curve(x^2, from=0 , to =1, col="darkblue")
curve(x^4, from=0 , to =1, add=T, col="darkred")
x <- c(seq(0, 1, 0.01), seq(1, 0, -0.01))
y <- c(x[1:101]^2, x[102:202]^4)
polygon(x,y, col = 'green', border = NA)
```

(extend the range of that last curve and see how using similar code treats the crossing curves yourself)

Comment: Also, note how the x values went first from 0 to 1 and then from 1 to 0 -- this is because for `polygon` you have to supply the vertices of the region you want shaded in (in order that you want the boundary drawn).

Comment: Thanx math.coffee, great comment!

Answer (score 1):

To generalise the accepted answer.. if you have two curves (two vectors) `f1(x1), f2(x2)` which satisfy `f1(x1) < f2(x2)` for all `x1,x2`, then you can use

```
#' @brief Draws a polygon between two curves
#' @f1,f2 Vectors satisfying f1 < f2
#' @x1,x2 Respective domains of f1, f2 
#' @... Arguments to ?polygon
ShadeBetween <- function(x1, x2, f1, f2, ...) { 
    polygon(c(x1, rev(x2)), c(f1, rev(f2)), ...)
}
```

For this specific example we have :

```
x <- seq(0,1,length=100)
matplot(x,cbind(x/2, x/4), type='l', col='white')
ShadeBetween(x,x, x/2, x/4, col='red')
```